# How do I retrieve Oracle DBMS_Output from a vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, plsql, oracle11g, dbms-output

I'm working on a vb.net application that executes an Oracle stored procedure.  The stored procedure displays a value using dbms_output.put_line.  How do I retrieve that value from the oracle database into my vb.net code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5653201/318499

Answer (score 1):

Provided the code executes in the same **database session** you can use DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE (or GET_LINES).  If it doesn't then you can't access it.